# Python os.system('dir') points to 'C:\' not 'C:\myfolder\'

Tags: python, os.system

Python os.system('dir') points to 'C:\' instead of 'C:\myfolder\'. Any ideas why and how can I fix it?
Environment: Windows 7, Python3.4

Comment: Why would it point to `C:\myfolder\ `  ? `os.system()` works in the current working directory , you must have started python from `C:\ ` , so `dir` shows results from that directory.

Comment: started from C:\myfolder\. using dir in cmd works fine.

Comment: What does `os.getcwd()` give?

Comment: os.getcwd() gives C:\myfolder\

Comment: That's bizarre. Try `os.system('echo %cd%')`

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this works for you.

```
import os
#Will print current working directory content
#That will be where the script is present
os.system("dir")
print "---------------------------------"
#Will print content of C:\Python27
os.system("dir C:\Python27")
```

Output

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>python chk.py
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 2A3D-7B34

 Directory of C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop

08/28/2015  01:56 PM    <DIR>          .
08/28/2015  01:56 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/19/2015  02:27 PM        27,156,654 a.bmp
08/31/2015  11:33 AM               187 chk.py
08/28/2015  11:20 AM               234 data.txt
08/13/2015  04:07 PM               502 eclipse - Shor
08/13/2015  03:39 PM               502 eclipse - Shor
06/24/2015  05:28 PM           876,888 freeSSHd.exe
08/27/2015  11:45 PM               970 FreeSSHd.lnk
05/27/2014  08:54 AM             1,073 Notepad++.lnk
05/21/2014  09:59 AM             1,892 P4V.lnk
05/20/2014  12:39 PM           520,192 putty.exe
08/28/2015  01:55 PM           567,978 sample.txt
              11 File(s)     29,127,072 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  15,955,296,256 bytes free
---------------------------------
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 2A3D-7B34

 Directory of C:\Python27

05/20/2014  08:00 PM    <DIR>          .
05/20/2014  08:00 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/20/2014  08:00 PM    <DIR>          DLLs
05/20/2014  08:00 PM    <DIR>          Doc
05/20/2014  08:00 PM    <DIR>          include
08/28/2015  10:20 AM    <DIR>          Lib
05/20/2014  08:00 PM    <DIR>          libs
11/10/2013  07:28 PM            38,573 LICENSE.txt
11/10/2013  11:15 AM           375,685 NEWS.txt
11/10/2013  07:24 PM            27,136 python.exe
11/10/2013  07:24 PM            27,648 pythonw.exe
10/27/2013  05:01 PM            55,208 README.txt
05/20/2014  08:00 PM    <DIR>          tcl
05/20/2014  08:00 PM    <DIR>          Tools
               5 File(s)        524,250 bytes
               9 Dir(s)  15,955,296,256 bytes free
```